# Two different model properties under single DataGrid column

Tags: c#, html, datagrid, blazor

I currently have the list `List<Entity>`. Inside this list are two models which are inherited from `Entity`, `Monster` and `Player`. I would like to have the `List<Entity>` in a DataGrid in Blazor. The problem is that due to reference, I required an extra property for the Monster Name (`Monster.EntityName`). What I would like is to have the DataGrid have the header "Name" with the values of `Monster.EntityName` if the `Entity` is a `Monster`, and `Player.Name` if the `Entity` is a `Player`

Is this possible, or do I need to create a EntityDataModel. And if so, is there anyway to keep the `List<Entity>` as leading database?

Edit for @RBee's reaction:

Entity Model:

```
public class Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int Id { get; set; } = -1;
        public int MaxHp { get; set; } = 0;
        public int Hp { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<int> Damage { get; set; } = new List<int> { };

        public int Init = 0;
        public int Ac { get; set; } = 10;
        public string ArmorType { get; set; } = "None";
        public string[] Speed { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string[] DmgVul { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string[] DmgRes { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string[] DmgImm { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string[] CondImm { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string[] Senses { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string[] Languages { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public List<NameValueCondition> Conditions { get; set; } = new List<NameValueCondition> { };
        public EntityHealthState HealthState => GetHealthState();
        private EntityHealthState GetHealthState()
        {
            if (Hp > MaxHp) return EntityHealthState.Overhealed;
            else if (Hp <= 0) return EntityHealthState.Dead;
            else if (Hp <= MaxHp / 4.0) return EntityHealthState.Critical;
            else if (Hp <= MaxHp / 2.0) return EntityHealthState.Bloody;
            else if (Hp < MaxHp) return EntityHealthState.Wounded;
            else return EntityHealthState.Healthy;
        }
    }
    public enum EntityHealthState
    {
        Overhealed,
        Healthy,
        Wounded,
        Bloody,
        Critical,
        Dead
    }
```

Player Model:

```
public class Player : Entity
    {
        public bool InParty { get; set; }
        public int InitiativeBonus { get; set; }
    }
```

Monster Model:

```
public class Monster : Entity
    {
        public string EntityName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Alignment { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int HitDiceNumber { get; set; } = 0;
        public int HitDiceSize { get; set; } = 0;
        public int HitDiceHp { get; set; } = 0;
        public int Str { get; set; } = 10;
        public int Dex { get; set; } = 10;
        public int Con { get; set; } = 10;
        public int Int { get; set; } = 10;
        public int Wis { get; set; } = 10;
        public int Cha { get; set; } = 10;
        public string[] SavThrProf { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string[] SkillProf { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public ChallengeRating Challenge { get; set; } = new ChallengeRating();
        public NameValuePair[] Traits { get; set; } = new NameValuePair[0];
        public NameValuePair[] Actions { get; set; } = new NameValuePair[0];

        public bool isSpellCaster { get; set; } = false;
        public int SpellSlots1 { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Spells1 { get; set; } = new List<NameValuePair> { };
        public int SpellSlots2 { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Spells2 { get; set; } = new List<NameValuePair> { };
        public int SpellSlots3 { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Spells3 { get; set; } = new List<NameValuePair> { };
        public int SpellSlots4 { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Spells4 { get; set; } = new List<NameValuePair> { };
        public int SpellSlots5 { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Spells5 { get; set; } = new List<NameValuePair> { };
        public int SpellSlots6 { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Spells6 { get; set; } = new List<NameValuePair> { };
        public int SpellSlots7 { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Spells7 { get; set; } = new List<NameValuePair> { };
        public int SpellSlots8 { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Spells8 { get; set; } = new List<NameValuePair> { };
        public int SpellSlots9 { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Spells9 { get; set; } = new List<NameValuePair> { };

        public bool isLegendary { get; set; } = false;
        public NameValuePair[] LegendaryActions { get; set; } = new NameValuePair[0];
        public string LegendaryDesc { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string LairActions { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string RegionalEffects { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public bool IsKnown = true;
        public bool IsUnseen = false;
        public bool IsAlly = false;
    }
```

What I've tried so far:

```
<GridView Data="@entities">
    <Columns>
        <GridViewColumn>
            <Header>Name</Header>
            <RenderFragment Context="context">
                @if (context is Monster monster)
                {
                    @monster.EntityName
                }
                else if (context is Player player)
                {
                    @player.Name
                }
            </RenderFragment>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </Columns>
</GridView>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (entity is Monster)
                {
                    var monster = entity as Monster;
                    <td>@monster.EntityName</td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>@entity.Name</td>
                }

                <td>
                    <button @onclick="() => RemoveMonster(entity)"> Remove </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table sort of works. But I'd rather have a DataGrid if that is possible.

Comment: Please show the class model, and what you've attempted so far.

Comment: I've added the extra information as you requested.

Comment: Now you need to share your GridView component. And please share just enough so that your problem can be reproduced. Like your models can be trimmed down to just show just the EntityName and Name as those are enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Judging by what you've posted so far, it looks like your problem lies in the GridView component's templates.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: if Monster inherits from Entity why not use the Name property of the base class ? 
  `<td>@monster.Name</td>` instead of `<td>@monster.EntityName</td>`

Comment: You can use an abstract function in your base class and override it in your inherited classes. Or you could override `ToString()` for each class. Or you use the name property from the base class.